# How do I get the code to pick random variable and then remove it from the list of possible choices

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, splice

I am barely breaking into the JS aspects of coding that I need for a little project I am working on, so I apologize ahead of time if I am not providing the information correctly.

So what I am trying to get this code to do is...

1. Remove the initial selection from the list of possible selections (appears to work?)
2. Create a variable containing the rest of the possible selections (I think I got it?)
3. Pick a random selection from that list (I think I got it?)
4. Then remove that selection from the possible selections so it is not chosen again. (it's broken)
5. Then loop it back around to run again until there are no more possible selections. (I'm clueless)

Side Note: I also don't know if there is a "cleaner" way to write this.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
// Target success chance.
var successRate = 0.90;
// Check if this succeeded.
if (Math.random() < successRate)  {
    // Determine the thunder element ID used for shock.
    var elementId = 7;
    // Damage formula used for the shock effect.
    var damage = user.mat * 3;
    // Check if a critical hit landed.
    if (target.result().critical) {
      // Apply critical damage.
      damage = this.applyCritical(damage);
    }
    // Get all of the alive members from the opponent's unit.
    var members = this.opponentsUnit().aliveMembers();
    // Remove the main target from the member list.
    members.splice(members.indexOf(target), 1);
    // Play the shock animation on the target.
    target.startAnimation(137);
    // Increase the damage received by the shock damage with the thunder multiplier.
    value += Math.ceil(damage * target.elementRate(elementId));
    // Other members of the opposite team need to be shocked.
    var extraTargets = members;
    // Loop each of these 4 members.
    while (extraTargets--) {
      // Get a random member from the opponent's team.
      var member = members[Math.floor(Math.random() * members.length)];
      // Check if the member exists.
      if (member) {
        // Play the shock animation on the random member.
        member.startAnimation(77);
        // Make the random member take damage with the thunder multiplier.
        member.gainHp(-Math.ceil(damage * member.elementRate(elementId)));
        // Start the damage popup on the random member.
   var text = 'damage';
   var motion = 'Pop High, Wait, Wait, Wait, Stretch';
   var font = 'this.standardFontFace()';
   var size = 'this.standardFontSize()';
   var color = '#BBFFFF';
   member.startDamagePopup().callCustomPopup(text, motion, font, size, color, x, y);
        // Clear the random member's results.
        member.clearResult();
        // Remove the random member from the list of valid targets.
        members.splice(members.indexOf(member), 1);
        // Check if the member is dead.
        if (member.isDead) {
          // If the member is dead, have it collapse.
          member.performCollapse();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

It will not loop through all of the possible selections and I don't know if it will remove the selection from the list of choices once it has been selected since I can't test that first part due to the loop failure...

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Where are all of these methods (ex. `.applyCritical()`) defined? They are obviously custom and far from standard. Do they come from a `Class`?

Comment: Like I mentioned before I am a novice so I am not sure I can answer that correctly, but they come from within the structure of the game creation engine I am using.

Comment: You can use reservoir sampling to randomly select items from a set without replacing them. I've used the [simple reservoir sampling algorithm from Wikipedia's page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling#Simple_algorithm). It is easy to implement and not too difficult to understand.

Comment: Your `while` loop won't start running because if the `members` variables is an array, then using the decrementing operator `(extraTargets--)` will return `NaN` which is false. This should be why the loop isn't running

Comment: What would I need to do or research then?

Comment: Use `var extraTargets = members.length;`

Comment: Well, I tried that and it runs but only selects one of the possible choices at random and stops lol. Still no loop unless I missed something or wrote it wrong which is mostly likely